# download image in asynchronous map function react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous

I am trying execute an asynchronous map over a list of image metadata objects.

For each object in the list, I check whether the string `device_path` exists on the device. If it does not, I download the image to the device using RNFetchBlob & the object's parameter `download_url`. After this I update the object's `device_path` to the newly downloaded image.

When executing the code below, my function `checkPaths` returns `{"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}`. I would like the function to return this:

```
[
  { device_path: 'goodimagepath1', download_url: 'mysecretdownloadurl1' },
  { device_path: 'goodimagepath2', download_url: 'mysecretdownloadurl2' }
];
```

How should I modify my function to work as intended?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";

async function checkPaths(image_metadata_list) {

  const promises = image_metadata_list.map(async (image_metadata, idx) => {

    RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(image_metadata.device_path).then(exists => {
      if (exists === false) {
        console.log("image does not exist on device, downloading...");
        const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
        const filename = (idx + 1).toString() + '.jpg'
        RNFetchBlob.config({
          path: dirs.DocumentDir + `/user_images/${filename}`
        }).fetch('GET', `${image_metadata.download_url}`).progress((received = 0, total = 0) => {
          //Handle progress of download here.. May be update UI...\
        }).then((resp) => {
          // update the device path
          image_metadata.device_path = resp.path();
          console.log("image path modified", image_metadata);
          return image_metadata;
        }).catch(e => {
          console.log("error downloading image", e);
        })
      }
      else {
        console.log("image path OK", image_metadata)
        return image_metadata;
      }
    })
  })
  console.log("promises", promises)
  results = await Promise.all(promises)
  return results;
}


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.image_references = [
       { device_path: 'badimagepath1', download_url:'mysecretdownloadurl1' },
       { device_path: 'badimagepath2', download_url: 'mysecretdownloadurl2' }
    ];
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component mounted");
    console.log("checking image paths", JSON.stringify(this.image_references));
    checked_paths = checkPaths(this.image_references);
    console.log("checked image paths", JSON.stringify(checked_paths));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Welcome to MWE</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since checkPaths is asynchronous, it returns a promise. This should be handled in `componentDidMount` like so:

```
checkPaths(this.image_references).then(checked_paths => {
      console.log("resolved promise", checked_paths)
      console.log("checked image paths", JSON.stringify(checked_paths));
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log("error checking image paths", e)
    });
```

I also modified the function `checkPaths` to await checking for the image path & to await downloading the image.

If there is a cleaner way to do this i'm all ears.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";

async function checkPaths(image_metadata_list) {

  const promises = image_metadata_list.map(async (image_metadata, idx) => {

    const exists = await RNFetchBlob.fs.exists(image_metadata.device_path)

    if (exists === false) {
      console.log("image does not exist on device, downloading...");
      const dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
      const filename = (idx + 1).toString() + '.jpg'

      const resp = await RNFetchBlob.config({
        path: dirs.DocumentDir + `/user_images/${filename}`
      }).fetch('GET', `${image_metadata.download_url}`).progress((received = 0, total = 0) => {
        //Handle progress of download here.. May be update UI...\
      }).then((resp) => {
        // update the device path
        image_metadata.device_path = resp.path();
        console.log("image path modified", image_metadata);
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log("error downloading image", e);
      })
    }
    else {
      console.log("image path OK", image_metadata);
    }
    return image_metadata;
  })
  return await Promise.all(promises);
}


export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.image_references = [
      { device_path: 'badimagepath1', download_url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fivedates-dev.appspot.com/o/user_images%2FoHK9DQ94ZZOBIejbVO8luJZnEU22%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=6c5e053d-45b4-4ab0-a52b-65c1180624ed' },
      { device_path: 'badimagepath2', download_url: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fivedates-dev.appspot.com/o/user_images%2FoHK9DQ94ZZOBIejbVO8luJZnEU22%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=6c5e053d-45b4-4ab0-a52b-65c1180624ed' }
    ];
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("component mounted");
    console.log("checking image paths", JSON.stringify(this.image_references));

    checkPaths(this.image_references).then(checked_paths => {
      console.log("resolved promise", checked_paths)
      console.log("checked image paths", JSON.stringify(checked_paths));
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log("error checking image paths", e)
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Welcome to MWE</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```